# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с логами Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Я/ использую магенто. У меня стоит мой плагин ImageRecyrcle. Скорее всего проблема в нём т.к. он фигурирует в логах. Очень хочется разобраться в чем же заключается ошибка или хотя бы узнать способ ее обнаружения. Спасибо всем кто отпишется.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Imagerecycle_Imagerecycle_Block_Core_Text' in TSA-UPGRADE/webroot/app/Mage.php:595
2017-04-03T15:21:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib/php/Imagerecycle/Imagerecycle/Block/Core/Text.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/vinnybyr:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 145

2017-04-03T15:21:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2017-04-03T15:21:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2017-04-03T15:21:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/local:/home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/community:/home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core:/home/vinnybyr/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2017-04-03T15:21:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib/php/Imagerecycle/Imagerecycle/Block/Core/Text.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/vinnybyr:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 145

2017-04-03T15:21:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2017-04-03T15:21:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Enterprise/Cms/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2017-04-03T15:21:25+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed
2017-03-24T20:49:42+00:00 ERR (3): exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Imagerecycle_Imagerecycle_Block_Core_Text' in /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
```

Это Stack Trace.

```
#0 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')

#1 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('core/text', Array)

#2 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('core/text', 'stripe.js')

#3 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('core/text', 'stripe.js')

#4 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

#5 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

#6 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()

#7 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()

#8 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()

#9 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')

#10 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#11 /home/vinnybyr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#12 /home/vinnyb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и написано в первой строке в вашем лэйауте есть блок с несуществующим типом:

```
Imagerecycle_Imagerecycle_Block_Core_Text
```

Первым делом проверьте существует ли он в принципе в коде модуля:

> app/code/{local или community}/Imagerecycle/Imagerecycle/Block/Core/Text.php

Если его нет, то скорее всего это опечатка в реврайте ( а судя из трейса ваш модуль реврайтит стандартный класс блока `Mage_Core_Block_Text`). В этом случае просто уберите реврайт в `config.xml` модуля.

**PS:** вообще в таких случаях стоит обращаться в поддержку разработчика модуля.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я уже удалил этот блок из конфига по тому что у него действительно нету реализации, но теперь я точно уверен что поступилправильно. Я бы обратился в поддержку если бы не был ей 